# Transformation of an object into a subclass object without loosing the references to the object

Tags: java, oop

This is my first problem I can't solve by searching. It's a general OOP problem, but the code is in java. Perhaps I miss an essential point?

Assume there is a baseclass and a subclass. An object of the baseclass is in many lists. There is a transformer class with one duty to transform the object into a subclass object. The transformer should not know anything about the lists. But as a result of the transformation the new subclass object should be in all the lists. (replace the former base class object)

Can this be done somehow?

```
class BaseClass {
    //
}
 class SubClass extends BaseClass{
    //
}
 class Transformer{
    BaseClass base;
    public Transformer(BaseClass base){
        this.base = base;
    }
    public void transform(){
        //transforms the Object to a subtype-object
        // ???
        // (move the references of the old object to the new one)
        this.base = new SubClass(); //something like this (but not so!!!)
    }
}


 class Programm{
    private List<BaseClass> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<BaseClass> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<BaseClass> list3 = new ArrayList<>();
    //many more Lists
    private List<BaseClass> listn = new ArrayList<>();



    public void main() {
        BaseClass myObject = new BaseClass();
        list1.add(myObject);
        list2.add(myObject);
        list3.add(myObject);
        listn.add(myObject);

        Transformer transformer = new Transformer(myObject);
        transformer.transform();

        //required result
        // All Lists contain the transformed Object (from Type SubClass)
    }
}
```

Comment: No. A `Dog` is an `Animal` but not all `Animal`s are `Dog`s. When you are transforming an `Animal` into a `Dog`, you must get more characteristics and attributes in order to do so. The nearest you get is the concept of "cloning" or "copying properties".

Comment: you have to iterate over all the lists replace the BaseClass objects with the SubClass objects

Comment: `//many more Lists` – You're sure you want that?

Comment: See it had been boring if Sun would have introduced generics that repeated the known shortcommings of c++ templates. So they thought a long time and eventually found ways to make it worse. One thing they came up with is called type erasure. That means you loose the type after compiling and you are not able to get hold on it.  Well and because that was such a nice trick, they did it analog with the class object. Well because of annoyed users(why?) they introduced one by one some workarounds - so now you can use reflection to some degree for such things. But do you realy want to go there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is luckily impossible (imagine if your objects started changing classes in the middle of your code). You can create a subclass object based on a superclass object (if you can sensibly fill in any missing properties), but you can't *turn* an existing object into its subclass (such that the reference equality would work as you're hoping in your example code, i.e. converting `myObject` would affect all the lists).

I don't know how you came up with this idea, but somewhere along the way you've gone down the wrong path. If you tell us what you're trying to achieve, we can provide you with a better solution.

Edit:
Since you're doing checkers and you need to crown a piece, you have the simple choice of adding a `boolean crowned` property to pieces, and writing logic based on that.

In a more complex situation you could for example use the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), where you would have a `Piece` class, and they would have a `Type` property that specifies the actual type of the piece. This way the object you put in lists (`Piece`) always stays the same, but if you replace its `Type` property, it would seem as if the piece magically changes it's type!

Comment: There are many ideas to go around the problem. I learn java (coming from swift). I develop a checker game app. In short: There is a class Board with the list of pieces. For simulation purposes there is a class Step. Within the step-class I do anything with the moving piece. The hope was to do the transformation of a piece into a king within this class Step. (there are many simple solutions - I know)

Comment: @M.P. if you know there are many simple solutions, why did you start with trying an impossible solution? Also see the edit for a proper solution.

Comment: Thank you for the edit (I will check the strategy pattern idea later). I encountered this problem and it is more an "academic" interest than a real "problem". (checked the strategy pattern! - I think its a good solution) - thank you!!!